# How do I split a string at certain points and collect what's in the middle of the split?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

Say I had some sample text

> jordan went to the shop to buy some bread end
>
> jordan sold some tomatos end
>
> jordan went to see his father end

If this was in a single string, how could I split this string at the words "Jordan" and "end" to get the text in the middle and put that into an array?

The output I expect is

```
string [] sArr = {
    "went to the shop to buy some bread",
    "sold some tomatos",
    "went to see his father"
}
```

Comment: Are the words you are looking for always "Jordan" and "end"?  Do you have to consider strings not matching the pattern "Jordan <text> end", if so what should be done with strings that does not match?

Comment: the pattern will always match, i used jordan and end as an example :)
 i looked at the split but i thought that only split on one character or a couple continuously 

my understanding of split would be if i had 

sArr = sentence.split("jordan") i would get back "went to the shop to buy some bread end and i dont want the "end"

Comment: You should try something first. This is pretty trivial.  Plenty of information out there about how to find the indexes of substrings and how to split strings into two or more.  StackOverflow shouldn't be your first resource.  You should be.  Come here once you get stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can do it using regular expressions:

```
var s = "jordan went to the shop to buy some bread end jordan sold some tomatos end jordan went to see his father end";
var list = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, @"jordan (.*?) end"))
{
    if(match.Success)
        list.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
}

var sArr = list.ToArray();
```

Or it can be done even more elegant with LINQ:

```
var sArr = Regex.Matches(s, @"jordan (.*?) end")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Where(m => m.Success)
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is what I am after @Andy Korneyev :) thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Split() method:

```
String str = "jordan went to the...";
String[] separator = new String[] { "jordan", "end"};
String[] res = str.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will give the output you're looking for.
Keep in mind that it will also keep any text between end and jordan.

Comment: This is what I am after Deadly Jesus :) thank you :)

Comment: Frankly, if this approach will be used on original OP's text - it will give some redundant strings containing only single space. That's why I went to regex-based solution.

Comment: It won't, because of `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.
EDIT: My bad, single-space != empty.

Comment: @DeadlyJesus It will. Just test it on the original string "jordan went to the shop to buy some bread end jordan sold some tomatos end jordan went to see his father end" and you'll see it - extra two strings containing single space in the resut array because of occurence "end jordan" in the text - so space is considered as item. Single space not considered as empty entry, I suppose.

Comment: A more serious problem is what happens with "Jordan approved the agenda end".

Answer (score 0):

You can replace them with an empty string if you want. Try this :

```
string str1 = "jordan went to the shop to buy some bread end";
        string str2 = "jordan sold some tomatos end";
        string str3 = "jordan went to see his father end";
        string total = str1 + str2 + str3;
        if ((total.Contains("jordan")==true) ||(total.Contains("end")) )
        {
            total = total.Replace("jordan", "");
            total = total.Replace("end", "");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Comment: This doesn't looks like something OP wants. Read the question - he wants array of original string splitted parts, not the string built by some replacements.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev That's right. But when I saw your answer for that, I made another method for the answer of the question.